# curl does not return any thing for protected file

Tags: linux, curl

I have a file on the server that is HTTP Head password protected, but when I tried to get the page the command returned with nothing at all:

```
curl --user username:password http://mysite.com
```

Comment: what does `curl -v --user ...` say (`-v` stands for verbose output)?

Answer (score 0):

The exit status (in shell variable `$?`) will tell you what failed. There is a table of meanings in the manual page. For interactive use, `-v` is more convenient.